# Using MSBuild to update the FILEVERSION in a C++ resource file causes compile failures

Tags: visual-c++, resources, msbuild

I have been tasked with automating our build process with msbuild.  We have about twenty Visual C++ projects and twenty C# projects making it a pain to hand edit all the version strings.  Our version numbers are meat-generated at build time, so we need to pass the full version string as a property on the command line.

My initial implementation used the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/)'s [`File`](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.3.0/html/f8c545f9-d58f-640e-3fce-b10aa158ca95.htm) task to do replacements on the `.rc` and `AssemblyInfo.cs` files.

```
<FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" Files="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" RegexPattern='\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(".*"\)\]' Replacement='[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$(Version)")]'/>
<FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" Files="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" RegexPattern='\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(".*"\)\]' Replacement='[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("$(Version)")]'/>
<FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" Files="@(RCFiles)" RegexPattern="FILEVERSION\s+\S+" Replacement="FILEVERSION $(Version)"/>
<FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" Files="@(RCFiles)" RegexPattern="PRODUCTVERSION\s+\S+" Replacement="PRODUCTVERSION $(Version)"/>
<FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" Files="@(RCFiles)" RegexPattern='VALUE\s+"FileVersion",\s*".*"' Replacement='VALUE "FileVersion", "$(Version)"'/>
<FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" Files="@(RCFiles)" RegexPattern='VALUE\s+"ProductVersion",\s*".*"' Replacement='VALUE "ProductVersion", "$(Version)"'/>
```

This is working great on the `AssemblyInfo.cs` files, but when I compile any of the C++ projects I get errors like this:

```
.\MyProject.rc(23): error RC2135: file not found: 0x09
.\MyProject.rc(71): error RC2135: file not found: 1
.\MyProject.rc(72): error RC2135: file not found: 6
.\MyProject.rc(73): error RC2135: file not found: 6
.\MyProject.rc(74): error RC2135: file not found: 0x3fL
.\MyProject.rc(80): error RC2135: file not found: FILEOS
.\MyProject.rc(81): error RC2135: file not found: 0x2L
.\MyProject.rc(84): error RC2164: unexpected value in RCDATA
.\MyProject.rc(86): error RC2135: file not found: BLOCK
.\MyProject.rc(88): error RC2135: file not found: VALUE
```

The first error is encountered on line 23, but when I diff `MyProject.rc` against source control everything looks OK.  Only the version numbers are changed, those changes begin on line 72, and the string `0x09` does not appear anywhere in the file.  What in the world is going on here?  Lines 21 - 25 look like this:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32
```

I'm also open to any suggestions on other methods to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: You have to replace the '.' with ',' in FILEVERSION to get it right in the File | Properties | Details tab of the DLL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Replace TaskAction was inserting Unicode characters while the rc files are using ASCII encoding.  Adding TextEncoding="ASCII" to all the rc replacement tasks results in compilable files.

A limitation of using the ASCII character set is that you can't use the © symbol.
But if you choose TextEncoding="Windows-1252" that solves the problem.

Comment: I was trying to do the same with the [MSBuild Community Tasks]'s(http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) `FileUpdate` task. They expose an `Encoding` property that works the same.

Comment: <!-- MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll Version  -->
 <FileUpdate Files="@(MyFiles01)"
  Regex="(&quot;Hello&quot;)"
  Encoding="Windows-1252"
  ReplacementText="&quot;GoodBye&quot;" ReplacementCount="0" Multiline="True" />

Comment: Upvote for Jared.  And Shout-out to Anthony M ... since I was using the MSBuild.Community.Tasks...and your (AnthonyM's) comment is what made my google search..find a match.  My issue was that without setting the encoding...I was getting some weirdo characters show up in my result.  The weirdo characters were:   ï»¿

Answer (score 4):

I would separate out the version information from the `AssemblyInfo.cs` and `*.rc` files.  Create an `AssemblyVersion.cs` and `Version.rc` file, which contain the (common) versioning information for all your assemblies.  You'd generate these at the start of your build.  Because they only contain the versioning information you don't have to use regular expressions, you can overwrite the entire file each time.

Comment: A decent suggestion.  Hand editing all those files once is certainly better than doing it every time we build, however we're still adding new projects to the build and it would be nice for those additions to be seamless.  Plus, my inherent programmer laziness makes me hold out hope for a solution that allows me to avoid any hand editing.

Comment: This is a valid recommendation even if you continue to use the automated solution. Any time you can avoid a regex, you're golden :)

Answer (score 3):

You still need to replace the periods (`.`) in the `FILEVERSION` with commas (`,`). If you  build without the correct format, you won't see the file version in the file's properties | details page. I would go ahead and do the same for the `PRODUCTVERSION`, although it doesn't seem to be necessary.

I used MSBuild [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx). I'm sure you can regex/replace them too.

```
<FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" 
                 TextEncoding="ASCII" 
                 Files="@(AppResource)" 
                 RegexPattern="FILEVERSION\s+\S+" 
                 Replacement="FILEVERSION $(Version.Replace('.',','))"/>
```

Comment: can you show me how you did with property. I am havign the same problem, but unable to solve it. @Anthony Mastrean